# Phone screen always on when using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, screen, launch

Do you know any way to keep the phone screen on when i run application on it from Eclipse?
I'm using my phone to test Android app and it is very annoying to turn on the screen every time i run the application.

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option Keep screen on under the developer options of your phone/emulator.

Comment: I know that, but i can accept answer after 15 minutes!

Comment: @smartmouse No problem, but sometimes some new user doesn't understand how stackoverflow works.